# Money Amounts on ArcGIS Web AppBuilder Infograhics

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, infographics

I am using Web App Builder in ArcGIS Enterprise and I have found Infographics to be quite useful in building dashboards.

Currently I am trying to use Infographics to display the money amount for a long integer. Does anyone know how I can get the money sign "$" or the 'K' in the denomination? As they have done in the example below.

Do I need to go back to the data-set and change the data type? Or do I need to use another widget to display the field? Could be something that's coded too but I don't know the answer.

[image: Dollar sign in Infographics]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dataFormat attribute to add commas, add a prefix character or a postfix character to your Infographic:  https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/api-reference/infographic.htm